# How to display images from array in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am very new to creating websites, but I am working on a simple project. I have an array where it lists the name of a Fruit and an gif image associated with each fruit. I want to create a drop down  where users can search or select a fruit and the name of the fruit and the gif image will appear. I was able to get most of it to work, but am having an issue getting the image to show up, right now its just appearing as a gif link.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

HTML Code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SolemnBotZ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesF.css">
</head>
<body>
      <label for="fruitinfos">Select a fruit:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fruitinfos" list="fruitinfoList" placeholder="Type to search...">
    
    <datalist id="fruitinfoList">
    </datalist>
    <div id="fruitinfoResult"></div>
    <div id="fruitinfoName"></div>
      <table id="fruitinfoTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Fruit</th>
            <th>Image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <th><div id="fruitinfoValue"></div></th>
          <th><img src="fruitinfoSprite"></th>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <script src="fruitinfo.js"></script>
      <script src="scriptest.js"></script>
      </body>
      </html
-------------------------------------------
Javascript Code


const fruitinfoSelect = document.getElementById('fruitinfoList');
fruitinfo.forEach((fruitinfo) => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = fruitinfo.name;
  option.value = fruitinfo.value;
  fruitinfoSelect.appendChild(option);
});

// Display selected fruitinfo value
function displayfruitinfo() {
  const fruitinfoSelect = document.getElementById('fruitinfos');
  const fruitinfoResult = document.getElementById('fruitinfoResult');
  const selectedValue = fruitinfoSelect.value;
  if (selectedValue !== '') {
    const selectedfruitinfo = fruitinfo.find((fruitinfo) => fruitinfo.value === selectedValue);
      fruitinfoName.innerHTML = `
        <div class="fruitinfo-box">
          <p>${selectedfruitinfo.name}</p>
        </div>`;
      fruitinfoValue.innerHTML = `
        <div class="fruitinfo-box">
          <p>${selectedfruitinfo.value}</p>
        </div>`;
    fruitinfoSprite.innerHTML = `
        <div class="fruitinfo-box">
        <p>${selectedfruitinfo.sprite}</p>
        </div>`;
  } else {
    fruitinfoResult.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

document.getElementById('fruitinfos').addEventListener('input', displayfruitinfo);


---------------------------------------------------

Fruit Array

const fruitinfo = 
[{"name":"orange","value":"Orange","sprite":"https://media0.giphy.com/media/iJgyjInSJyTxNYlEfx/giphy.gif?cid=6c09b952d896a56e1d9c1f71daf0e82923fa81447709142a&rid=giphy.gif&ct=s"},
{"name":"apple","value":"Apple","sprite":"https://media.tenor.com/1HdVv6rRFcQAAAAM/excited-apple.gif"},
{"name":"banana","value":"Banana","sprite":"https://img1.picmix.com/output/stamp/normal/6/4/3/4/1754346_b0227.gif"},
{"name":"watermelon","value":"Watermelon","sprite":"https://media2.giphy.com/media/l2JJuGNzLVmLDcD0Q/giphy.gif"},
{"name":"lemon","value":"Lemon","sprite":"https://media4.giphy.com/media/jTMPEWFcgbEYc95yF5/giphy.gif"},
{"name":"grape","value":"Grape","sprite":"https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/56a8aa84301127.5d587dbe6f5d2.gif"},
{"name":"mango","value":"Mango","sprite":"https://media2.giphy.com/media/SXNbTnAVzfv9NvEyRE/200w.gif?cid=6c09b9523jcd3cpliienj5jgisee2393douikwx5la7zshdt&rid=200w.gif&ct=s"}
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the URL into an <p>. These elements are for displaying text.

The <img>-Element is what you are looking for.

```
    fruitinfoSprite.innerHTML = `
    <img class="fruitinfo-box" src="${selectedfruitinfo.sprite}" alt="${selectedfruitinfo.value}">`;
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, greatly appreciate the the document too!